# Issues customizing Jira - White Label possible?

Tags: jira

I'm learning more and more about JIRA server (installed on my server) and I have some questions.  I did search quite a lot but I guess you guys can help me more!

1) is there a way to customize all those strings such as

" Before we begin, choose the language you want to use in Jira. "
" Welcome to Jira, userxxx! "

I would like to "white label" as much as possible and remove any reference to the word Jira.

2) Skip the avatar step when user log in for the first time?

3) Skip " What Would you like to do now? when user log in for first time.  Basically, I want the user to go straight to the dashboard

4) Remove the whole footer?

5) Remove menu items such as Dashboards and Boards?  Keep it very simple for the users.

Your feedback are welcome!

Thank you
Nathalie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can customize almost any string by modifying the corresponding velocity template. Search in the directory {JIRA_INSTALL}/atlassian-jira/WEB-INF/classes/ for the string you want to change. But you should be very careful and know what you are doing as you will be changing the source code!
2. Should be gone by disabling the onboarding filter: [(Source)](https://confluence.atlassian.com/jirakb/how-to-disable-user-onboarding-in-jira-6-4-and-above-702714311.html)

   1. Navigate to `{jiraBaseUrl}/secure/SiteDarkFeatures!default.jspa`
   2. Add `jira.onboarding.feature.disabled` to the dark features
3. See 2.
4. According to the Atlassian Software License Agreement 3.6 you are not allowed to remove or change the "Powered by Atlassian" from the footer. [(Source)](https://www.atlassian.com/legal/software-license-agreement)
5. You can remove them by adding a simple css snippet to the announcement banner:

   ```
   <style type="text/css">
   #home_link, #greenhopper_menu {display: none;}
   </style>
   ```

   (Your selectors may differ depending on your Jira version.)

Although all of this is somehow possible, I would strongly advise not to implement the 1. and the 5. point. The first one is a support hell, because you have to keep track of every single change you did and for each update you have to diff all the files (which can change from version to version). Furthermore the more you customize Jira, the more you'll have to help your users, as the documentation they will find at Atlassian will differ from your instance. This although applies to the fifth point and additionally boards and dashboards are the key features of Jira along with JQL imho. Check also the community at https://community.atlassian.com/ as they might be a better source for your questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure the terms and conditions from Atlassian for using Jira explicitly say you cannot remove the word "Jira" from Jira. It's their brand - why would they want to let you?